# Possible to create a login wall?

Tags: login

I have a website that offers a lot of free information. I get a lot of outbound clicks on my site do to all of the informative links to other web pages. My question is - Is it possible to force a user to sign up or login to my site when they click on any link? Then once they are signed up, the links will work as normal.

Comment: This [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/) can help you out. Use imagination to make it work exact as you want.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find that I could use a pop up that doesn't go away unless an action is performed does the trick. I put a pricing table inside a popup, seemed to do the trick.